# detect iPad full screen web-app

Tags: jquery, ipad, web-applications, mobile-safari

So iPad's full screen web-app feature is super cool, but I have a problem with it.

The status bar of the ipad covers up part of the page! Just a little bit, but its still a problem. I would like to add padding to the top of the `body` element to account for this, but ONLY in full screen web app mode.

I am at a loss on how to detect this. Has anyone found a way to add padding to the top so that a full screen web app does not have overlap?

Comment: Is this a feature of the iPad or Mobile Safari?

Comment: Yes. Use the 'web app capable metatag' and then use 'add to home screen'. Its pretty cool.

Comment: Oh, I knew about that one. Answer coming up :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out this property...

```
var isRanFromHomeScreen = navigator.standalone;
```

This will tell you if your application has been added to the home screen and is running from there.

Comment: now is there a way to calculate the amount of height that would need to be added?

Comment: @Fresheyeball Not sure, but it should be consistent, try adding `10px`.